# Saving html file add � in file

Tags: c#, html, utf-8

I a reading an html file as string and after adding some html tags i am saving it again, but when I save this file � sign shows in edited html file in browser.
This is the code

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath.FullName, Encoding.UTF8);
// adding an html tag <input type="hidden" name="userInfo" />
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath.FullName, changedFileContent, Encoding.UTF8);
```

here is a screenshot of edited html file in browser

[image]

Comment: The html file has some other encoding. May be UTF-16. Try removing Encoding.UTF8 by Encoding.Default

Comment: Encoding.Default  worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Bharat Gupta's Comment I used Default Encoding and it solved the issue.

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath.FullName, Encoding.Default);
// adding an html tag <input type="hidden" name="userInfo" />
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath.FullName, changedFileContent, Encoding.Default);
```